# How to get the first visible View from an Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Is there a way to get the first visible View out of the ListView in Android?

I can get the data that backs the first View in the Adapter but it seems I can't get the first View in ListView.

I want to change the first visible view after a scroll action finished. I know that I should not save references to the view.

Comment: The views are recycled. What do you need the specific view for?

Comment: I edit my question. I want to change the view after the user scrolled the list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually ListView items are just children of ListView. So first visible ListView item is:

```
listView.getChildAt(0)
```

Comment: thank you works great if you probe the returned view for null. It seems that scrolling and list building sometimes happen at the same time if you start the activity and sometimes the list does not have a child.

Comment: I think this way is wrong. Because you get first item that loaded. and maybe that item isn't first visible. But listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() is better and work well always.

Comment: Not accurate if there are headers.

Answer (score 4):

ListView has a function `getFirstVisiblePosition` so to get the first visible view, the code would be:

`listView.getChildAt(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());`

Comment: There is a difference between the childAt() position and the position that is returned by getFirstVisiblePosition(). The position of getFirstVisiblePosition is the position in my data adapter. ChildAt only takes the views into account that are visible in the listview at the moment.

Comment: I liked the answer and found it useful to find something working. Yet using childAt with the position in the adapter wsill not work. If you use fetFirstVisiblePosition, you have to pass that along again to the adapter using getItem. So more correct would be adapter.getItem(listview.getFirstVisiblePosition). Yet, in that case you don't have the view as the op asked. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed `listView.getChildAt(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition())` gives the first visible item, 
BUT it could be **half visible** list item.

To get first completely visible list item,

```
if (listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() < 0) {
     int firstCompletelyVisiblePos = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object item = listView.getItemAtPosition(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

For first completely visible list item:

```
int pos = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
if (listView.getChildCount() > 1 && listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() < 0) pos++;
Object item = listView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= conversationListView.getLastVisiblePosition() - conversationListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {
        View listItem = conversationListView.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

listView.scrollBy(0, -40);

This works very well