# ListView with first visible item having different layout

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I make the first visible element of the `ListView` having a different `layout` from the others.

[image: the first cell have a description]

[image: when is list is scrolled and 2nd cell is at first position the description of the 2nd cell is shown]

I have created a custom adapter with 2 different layouts. Now, how can I make the `layout` change  when the item comes in the first `position`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to get the the first item of the listview having a different layout the following code can be used. But the listview don't move when the items in the list are less than the no of visible items.

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(firstItem != firstVisibleItem)
            {
                firstItem = firstVisibleItem;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

and inside the adapter class check if the `postion` is same as `firstItem` if its equal then show the detals layout.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

int visibleposition = ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

now for this particular position change the background of the list item like this

Comment: hii. i tried this method and it works. but the problem is that if the all of items in the 'listview' are visible without scrolling ie 'totalItemCount' is less than or equal to 'visibleItemCount' the 'listview' dosn't move. so only the details of the first item can be seen.

Comment: also the last few elemets in the list can never come in the details segment as they never come in the first postion.

Comment: I guess this is what you require. U want only those list items to come into detail segment which are in the first visible position.

Comment: sorry. i meant listview donst scroll. the listview is scrolable only when the no of elements vislible is less than the to total no of elemets in the list.

Comment: u cannot scroll a list if the all the items in your list are visible in your screen

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23479/discussion-between-bill-gates-and-swati)

Answer (score 0):

In getView(), you might inflate a different layout for different position. do something like

```
 if(position==0){
           inflate(first_layout);
   else{
           inflate(other_layout);
```

Comment: it's not what he needs. Just check how it works. It will not make the first visible item have a different layout, it will make a diff layout only for the very first item. The question is tricky and interesting.

Comment: This will only change the layout of the first item in the list and not the first visible item. i want each cell to change its layout when it reaches the first visible position.

Comment: but this answer is what I need :) but can't vote up since different topic

Answer (score 0):

You can try some method such as

> getFirstVisiblePosition

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110927/how-to-get-the-first-visible-view-from-an-android-listview) might answer your problem

Comment: this will change only the very first item if I am not mistaken and will not change the first item dnamically.

Comment: Now i understand his question. my apologize