# Android get listview first visible position from adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I need your help. Is it possible to get listview's first visible position from adapter?

So far what I've tried is to get the position and just pass it back to the activity. But it is not what I actually wanted. I need to get the first visible item and scroll to it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you implement AbsListView.OnScrollListener to your adapter, you can get first visible position in the onScroll method: onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalItems)

Comment: @mjp66 thanks. can you give sample code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first visible View from an Android ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110927/how-to-get-the-first-visible-view-from-an-android-listview)

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity or Fragment, implement an OnScrollListener on your listview. This is what it looks like, though it won't do anything yet except, well, listen ;)

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, 
            int visibleCount, int totalItems) {

    }

});
```

Here's some fun stuff you could do in the `OnScrollStateChanged()` method... for example, you might want to perform some kind of action every time the listview is scrolled or flung (in the following example, we're just going to generate a Toast message):

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    switch (scrollState) {
    case  SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
        Toast.makeText(context, "flinging", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
        Toast.makeText(context, "touch scrolling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

The `onScroll()` method though is what probably interests you more. In the following example, we'll generate a Toast message when the first visible position and last visible position change:

```
int currentFirst = 0;
int currentLast = 0;

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible,
        int visibleCount, int totalItems) {
    int lastVisible = firstVisible + visibleCount - 1;
    if (currentFirst != firstVisible && currentLast != lastVisible) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "first visible position = " + firstVisible
            + ", last visible position = " + lastVisible, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        currentFirst = firstVisible;
        currentLast = lastVisible;
    }
}
```

In the `onScroll()` example above, you can see how to get both the first visible item and the last visible item in the listview:

**first visible:** `int firstVisible`

**last visible:** `int firstVisible` + `int visibleCount` - 1;